# Embed HTML in Batch file

Tags: html, batch-file

Is there any way to create and execute from a `.bat` file or embed the HTML in `.bat` file.

I need HTML to write/read to a file in a local folder. This HTML I should be able to execute it using a `.bat`.

Is it possible?

Comment: HTML is not an "executable" language, you can't "execute" HTML.

Comment: Yes, you can create HTML with the [`echo`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490897.aspx) command.

Comment: You can already read/write local files in batch files. You don't need HTML to do so.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
(echo ^<html^>
echo ^<b^>Hello world^</b^>
echo ^</html^>
)>test.html
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo ^<html^> > test.html
echo ^<b^>Hello world^</b^> >> test.html
echo ^</html^> >> test.html
```

To open this HTML in default browser use:

```
start test.html
```

Comment: Looks like fun. Someone's got a plan for the weekend!